# what are the possible reasons for 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int' in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, database-size, cast

When this command is run, there is SQL server error

> 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int'.

```
SELECT sum(size) FROM [dbname]..sysfiles sf, [dbname]..sysfilegroups sfg WHERE sfg.groupname = 'PRIMARY' AND sf.groupid = sfg.groupid
```

Because the file size is less than 16TB, `bigint` is not required. Still I tried to execute cast(size as `bigint`), the error persists.

```
SELECT sum(cast(size as bigint)) FROM [dbname]..sysfiles sf, [dbname]..sysfilegroups sfg WHERE sfg.groupname = 'PRIMARY' AND sf.groupid = sfg.groupid
```

So the question is, what are the reasons for arithmetic overflow error other than exceeding the file size limit of 16TB.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you restructure the query to use a `JOIN` predicate like so? `SELECT sum(size) FROM [dbname]..sysfiles AS sf JOIN [dbname]..sysfilegroups AS sfg ON sf.groupid = sfg.groupid WHERE sfg.groupname = 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: Also, if you are using SQL Server 2008 and above, you should use the `sys.database_files` and `sys.filegroups` catalog views instead of the compatability views. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql)

Comment: I would also suggest a test run with `SELECT sf.*` instead of `SELECT sum(size)`, to validate that you're getting back the number of rows you expect, and the values are what you expect.

Comment: Assuming SQL >= 2005, the syntax that you are using and the system catalog views were deprecated as of SQL Server 2005. Try the following: `SELECT SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, df.[size])) AS [Total] FROM sys.database_files df INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces ds ON ds.[data_space_id] = df.[data_space_id] WHERE ds.[name] = N'PRIMARY';`. That's just an updated version of your 2nd query. If you get the error, try: `SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, df.[size]))) AS [Total] FROM sys.database_files df INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces ds ON ds.[data_space_id] = df.[data_space_id] WHERE ds.[name] = N'PRIMARY';`.

Comment: Exec your code this way: `SELECT sum(size *1.) FROM sysfiles sf, sysfilegroups sfg WHERE sfg.groupname = 'PRIMARY' AND sf.groupid = sfg.groupid` to find out the final size without getting any error and then post it here please

Comment: Ran 'SELECT sum(size *1.) FROM sysfiles sf, sysfilegroups sfg WHERE sfg.groupname = 'PRIMARY' AND sf.groupid = sfg.groupid', i'm getting 512, and 568 in test systems. I couldn't run this command on the production system yet. will update the results when i get access to production system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-- casting using DECIMAL(38,2) throws exception, Size needs to be casted as bigint

> select [SizeInMB] = CAST( ((SUM(Size)* 8) / 1024.0) AS DECIMAL(38,2) ) from sys.master_files

-- This fix is sufficient, but cannot limit to 2 decimal digits

> select [SizeInMB1] = ((SUM(CAST(Size AS BIGINT))* 8) / 1024.0)  from sys.master_files

-- 2 decimal digits are not available in fix, as divide by 1024.0 converts to default 6 digits

> select [SizeInMB2] = ((SUM(CAST(Size AS DECIMAL(38,2)))* 8) / 1024.0)  from sys.master_files

-- so 2 casts are required to eliminate Arithmetic overflow exception and limiting 2 decimal digits

> select [SizeInMB3] = CAST( ((SUM(CAST(Size AS BIGINT))* 8) / 1024.0) AS DECIMAL(38,2) ) from sys.master_files